# How to parse JsonArray which is inside JsonArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
[{
    "image": "img\/notice_image\/images_1.jpg",
    "noticeImage": ["img\/notice_image\/68739society.png"]
}, {
    "image": "img\/notice_image\/(24).jpg",
    "noticeImage": ["img\/notice_image\/39040(309)~1.JPG", "img\/notice_image\/2187800x600_157.jpg", "img\/notice_image\/99373455844_0.JPG"]
}]
```

this is the JSON i am getting from server. I need all the urls under "noticeImage" to be added in arraylist.

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Comment: Whatever lenguage your using just use the language function to encode json to array and run over the array like that. `for $i=0; $i<count($array);$i++){$array_notice_images = $array[$i]["noticeImage"];for($j;$j<count($array_notice_images);$j++){echo ($array_notice_images[$j]);}`

Comment: What's with the backslashes?

Comment: I need the solution for my android project, where iam getting such urls from server

Answer (score 0):

In the success Callback Function write JavaScript this code

```
var arrayList = [];
var length= data.length;
   for(i=0; i<length; i++ ){
       arrayList.push(data[i].noticeImage) 
    }
//do some stuff
```

> data in this context is the response of the successCallback function

Comment: arrayList is another array. Better iterate over it to get each urls.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var array = JSON.parse(jsonStringFromServer),
    noticeImages = [];

for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
  noticeImages[i] = array[i].noticeImage;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmrv2dtL/4/

Comment: noticeImages is another array. Better iterate over it to get each urls.

Answer (score 0):

A better one for Android [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

The **[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)** class is to parse your String Json to a Json Object. Then call getJSONArray(String name) that returns a **[JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)**

I think your String is a JSONArray.

Example: Not tested yet

```
String yourJson;
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(yourJson);
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
   JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
   JSONArray jArrayImages = jobj.getJSONArray("noticeImage");
   for(int j=0;j<jArrayImages.length();j++){
       String url = jArrayImages.getString(j);
       //your stuff with url.
   }
}
```

Feel free to try and catch when asking.

Comment: @tooni thanks for the reply. But i need the solution for my android project, in which iam using JAVA as a programming language and i am using Volley networking library for parsing JSON. Can you help me in this case.
Thank you